# How do I Debug a SingleFileGenerator/ Custom Tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, customtool

I am building a Custom Tool code generator using the Visual Studio SDK and basing it on the SingleFileGenerator example.

My question is how to enter debug mode on this code? I can currently add my custom tool to a file in Visual Studio but it errors out, I'd like to be able to debug this code if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to debug Visual Studio, you can either do it by attaching to a running session *(Tools\Attach To Process)* or by setting Visual Studio (devenv.exe) to be your startup project of the Custom Tool Project.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try and elaborate Jeff's answer:

1. Open the custom tool project (AKA: proj1)
2. Open a test project (aka: proj2) and define the file's custom tool to point to the wanted custom tool.
3. in proj1: create a break point and attach to process of p2.
4. in proj2: save the file and the break point will spring in p1 allowing you to debug.

Hope it helps.